# Updating Current Location in Google Maps using UIWebview in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, uiwebview, maps, driving-directions

I have a WebView I created in app which calls Google Maps Directions to plot out the route between the Current Location and a POI.

The entire google map with directions is loaded as soon as the webView loads. Now I need to update the map with my current location. As in, I want the flag/icon representing my current location to move along with the user while he is travelling. But the only way I seem to be able to do this so far, is reloading the entire map by calling the new location.

This is very expensive in both time/data usage. Is there a better way that I'm missing ?

Here's my code :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D destination = { 37.773768,-122.408638 }; 

NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&output=embed",
                                            myLocation.coordinate.latitude, myLocation.coordinate.longitude, destination.latitude, destination.longitude];



NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString];
NSURLRequest *requestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Someone please help !!!

Comment: I think you would need to set the location managers distance filter to probably 5 meters... and do this. Yes, it is very memory consuming.... but I am pretty sure it is the only way

Comment: so reload the entire map each time you want to update current location ? That sounds very tedious. Is there no other way ? Google Devs on the forum please answer !!

Comment: I don't think there is another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [GeolocationMarker](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocationmarker/) from the [Google Maps API 3 Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries). It was created for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

u can use..
CLLocationManager for getting user's location
UIWebview is not use for location fetching..